Does there exist a 5-connected maximal planar graph that is perfect?
A graph $G$ is said to be perfect if $\chi(H)=\omega(H)$ hold for any
induced subgraph $H_i\subseteq G$ (and so for $G$ itself, too)
For maximal planar graphs with connectivity  3, it is easy to construct a class of perfect graphs, such as  planar 3-trees. For the connectivity 4, we can also construct infinitely many examples, like graphs in the previous link Are there examples of non-perfect graphs among these graphs (Thanks to Misha Lavrov). However, for the  connectivity 5, I have not yet found a corresponding example. Could it be that any 5-connected (maximal) planar graph is not perfect?
The following is SageMath code (Sage 10.3) for searching. I haven't seen it yet:
# Generate 5-connected maximal planar graphs using the Plantri generator
# Note: The value 12 can be adjusted to a higher number for generating larger graphs 
gen = graphs.plantri_gen("12 -c5 ")

# Use a generator expression to find the first perfect graph

p = next((g for g in gen if g.is_perfect()), None)
if p is not None:
    print(p)
else:
    print("No graphs found")



I seem to have found evidence because it always contains a 5-hole (the structure around a vertex of degree 5; 5-connectivity ensures that the neighborhood of this vertex induces a cycle of length 5).

I don't see how 5-connectivity ensures that the neighborhood of this vertex induces a cycle of length 5, can you elaborate more on that? I can show that such a graph is not chordal, so there will be an induced cycle of length $4$.

I will add a solution right away. If you prove it contains an induced 4-cycle, you can provide an answer. Thank you.

I think I just proved a small property of the graph -- not very sure how it solves anything. It cannot be a chordal graph because chordal graphs are recursively constructed via clique sums of complete graphs. If $G$ is $5$-connected, the summands must be $K_t$ for $t \geq 6$ -- but then $G$ cannot be planar.

Let  $G$ be a 5-connected maximal planar graph. It is easy to prove that the minimum degree of $G$ is 5. Let $v$ be a vertex of degree $5$ and $N_G(v)=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Then, based on maximality, the local drawing of $N[v]$ is as follows:

Then $123451$ is a 5-cycle. Moreover, this 5-cycle cannot have a chord $xy$ where $1\le x<y \le 5$; otherwise, $xvyx$ would form a separating 3-cycle of $G$.
(For example,  $x=1, y=4$,  then there are vertices both inside (vertex $5$) and outside (vertex $2$) the cycle $1v4$. Vertices $1, 4, v$ form a 3-separator.)
This contradicts the 5-connectivity.

So $G$ is not perfect.

Why should $xvyx$ separate $G$?

@koifish I added some explanations.

Right, I think that works!

Nice proof, looks good!

@Brandon du Preez The proof cannot be extended to any planar graphs with connectivity 5 or minimum degree 5.  I even believe that any planar perfect graphs has minimum degree 4. I plan to ask a new question.

@BrandonduPreez A new question can be seen in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4934194/does-there-exist-a-5-connected-planar-graph-that-is-perfect
